# Run into segmentation fault when doing string manipulation in C

Tags: c, segment, bus-error

I'm working on removing obfuscating a substring from the main string in C. The substring has a format of `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` where `x` can be a number or a letter. The beginning of the substring always have a space, but the end of the substring doesn't always have a space.

e.x. the input can be `"Found new device with wlan 33:33:33:33:33:33. Total 4 devices connected"` 
the output should be `"Found new device with wlan *. Total 4 devices connected"`

I need to make a helper function to do so, and this is what I come up with:

```
//find the first occurency of ":" record as first_position_ptr and the last occurency of ":" record as last_position_ptr. 
// Add 2 to first_position_ptr to beginning of the substring and set it to "*"
// Subtract 2 from the last_position_ptr to get the pointer of the last charactor in substrung. 
// Iterate from 1 + first_position_ptr to last_position_ptr - 2 and set inStr to 0 to deleted the rest of substring. 

const char *proc(char *inStr) {
    const char tar[] = ":";
    char *first_position_ptr = strchr(inStr, tar[0]);
    char *last_position_ptr = strrchr(inStr, tar[0]);

    int first_position = (first_position_ptr == NULL ? -1 : first_position_ptr - inStr);
    int last_position = (last_position_ptr == NULL ? -1 : last_position_ptr - inStr);

    if (first_position != -1 && last_position != -1) {
        inStr[first_position + 2] = "*";
    }

    for (int i = (first_position + 1); i < (last_position + 2); i++) {
        inStr[i] = 0;
    }
    return inStr;
}

int main() {
    const char str[] = "Found new device with wlan 33:33:33:33:33:33. Total 4 devices connected";
    proc(*str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile the code, I run into these warnings:

```
Jeff-MacBook-Pro-2:Desktop jBerman$ gcc test.c -o test
test.c:35:29: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from
      'char [2]' [-Wint-conversion]
                inStr[first_position + 2] = "*";
                                          ^ ~~~
test.c:43:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
test.c:49:7: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'const char' to
      parameter of type 'char *' [-Wint-conversion]
        proc(*str);
             ^~~~
test.c:26:24: note: passing argument to parameter 'inStr' here
const char* proc(char *inStr){
                       ^
3 warnings generated.
```

When I run it, the compile says:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

So I tried to correct this line in main:

```
proc(*str) -> proc(&str);
```

The compiler return:

```
Bus error: 10
```

Can someone let me know what might be wrong please? Or if you help more efficient way of doing this, please let me know

Comment: `proc(*str)`-->`proc(str)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `str` to `proc`, not `*str` and define `str` as a modifiable `char` array.
The `proc` function should also be simplified: setting the characters in the middle to zero does not erase the middle portion, it makes the string stop after the `*`. To keep the end of the string, you must copy it with `memmove()`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// replace the mac address from the input string with a *
char *proc(char *inStr) {
    char *p1 = strchr(inStr, ':');
    char *p2 = strrchr(inStr, ':');

    if (p1) {  // no need to test p2, there is at least one ':' in the string
        /* backtrack 2 characters, but not before the start of inStr */
        if (p1 > inStr) p1--;
        if (p1 > inStr) p1--;
        /* skip 3 characters, but not past the end of the string */
        p2++;
        if (*p2) p2++;
        if (*p2) p2++;
        /* replace the MAC address with a '*' */
        *p1++ = '*';
        /* move the rest of the string, including the null terminator */
        memmove(p1, p2, strlen(p2) + 1);
    }
    return inStr;
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "Found new device with wlan 33:33:33:33:33:33. Total 4 devices connected";
    printf("%s\n", proc(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The code works great. I just have some questions about code. For example, I tried to change the two `if (p1 > inStr) p1--;` to `if (p1 > inStr) p1-2;` it still has the first 2 characters of the substring left

Comment: @ImTrying: `p1-2` does not modify `p1`, `p1 -= 2;` would decrement `p1` by 2, but if the string starts with `a:`, this would make `p1` point before the beginning of the string. This explains why I had 2 lines `if (p1 > inStr) p1--;` and a comment explaining the logic.

Comment: Hi, I was running this code on a bash shell which it works perfectly. But when I tried to run this program on sh shell it is causing a Bus Error. I think the skipping pointers are causing this. Could you let me know someway that u can fix this please?

Comment: @ImTrying: Which code are you running? what system do you use? how do you compile the code? How do you run the code? The code in my answer does not use command line arguments, nor read standard input, it should not make a difference if you run it from `bash` or `sh`.

Comment: sorry for responding late, I was trying some alternative ways. I was running your code in this reply. The running system uses a MIPS with a bash shell. I made my files and compile them in a Make File: `$(MAKE) -C $@` 
I don't think I read std input

Comment: @ImTrying: Does the my code produce `Found new device with wlan *. Total 4 devices connected` on your system?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: @ImTrying: this is quite surprising. Do you compile the program on the same system as you run it? Do you type `make` from the bash prompt?

Comment: No I do now. I tested your code on local (Ubuntu 64 bit), and it works absolutely fine. But when I transfer to an MIPs bash shell device. The system crushed. But no worries, let me do more investigate. And again, thank you for helping me

Comment: Do you transfer the executable to the MIPS device? The executable code cannot run there without recompilation for the proper target.

Comment: Hmm you might be right. Let me explain my set up:
I have: 
`char *proc(char *inStr) {...}

void funcA(const char* event)
{
  ....

    int len = strlen(event);
    char bufferEvent[len];
    strcpy(bufferEvent, event);

    logFile(logFormat(), proc(bufferEvent));
}`

Comment: I declared the helper function proc in front of the function I want to apply to later. In that function I copied the "event" to a buffer since the even is declared as constant char. I applied the proc on the buffer and then use a pre made log function to print it

Comment: `char bufferEvent[len]` should be `char bufferEvent[len+1]` to allow for the null terminator. If you test code that is different from what you post in the question, the answers will be incomplete.

Comment: Wait, sorry what you have just pointed out was exactly the mistake. I'm so sorry. And I really appreciated your help